# Is this probability calculation right? (99% chance of winning a 1 in 20,000 random game)

Tags: probability

The odds of winning in a game are 1 out of 20,000. How many times would one have to play the game in order to be sure they would win?

Let n be the number of times you need to play

The probability of not winning the game 1 - 1/20000= 19999/20000.

Using this probability calculation below:

1 - (19,999/20,000)ⁿ

As I understand I should solve for n and equal something like ~0.009 to represent a 99% of winning.

So what I found is n = 94,000

Is it fair to say if there are 94,000 players of the game with a 1 in 20,000 chance of winning (no skill involved) that there is a 99% chance that someone wins?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How did you obtain $94~000$? The equation is
$$
\left( \frac{19~999}{20~000} \right)^n = \frac{1}{100}
$$
and I get $n\approx 92~101$

Comment: ah, it's true. Thanks Henry.

Comment: Not that it is much easier, but $\frac{\log(0.01)}{\log\left(1-\frac1{20000}\right)} \approx 92101.1$ is close to $-20000\log_e(0.01) \approx 92103.4$

Comment: Thanks!  As you can see I was finding an ~approximate amount but this is much better.  It's been a while and didn't think about doing = 1/100

Comment: Actually I don't know how to do that calculation by hand, I know how to do 1/100 = x/500 for example but how do you calculate that when there is an exponent n?

Comment: In the body, you ask , how many games are needed to win surely ? The answer to this question is : "Infinite many games". You can approach probability $1$ as close as you want by playing enough games, but you can never reach it.

Comment: @Steven: you take logarithms - with a calculator or tables from a book but not by hand.

Comment: @Henry Ok thanks, I found this site to do it https://www.symbolab.com/solver/equation-calculator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is it fair to say if there are 94,000 players of the game with a 1 in 20,000 chance of winning (no skill involved) that there is a 99% chance that someone wins?"

It would be better to say there is 99% that at least one person wins.